# How to augment typed npm module types?

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to augment the types in the [iam-policies](https://github.com/Rogger794/iam-policies) npm package.

Specifically, I am attempting to augment the ConditionKey type, or anything that will get me to the result that I want.

Here's what the [types file for the package](https://github.com/Rogger794/iam-policies/blob/master/src/types.ts) look like:

```
export declare type ConditionKey = string | number | boolean;
...
declare type Resolver = (data: ConditionKey, expected: ConditionKey) => boolean;
export interface ConditionResolver {
    [key: string]: Resolver;
}
export interface Context {
    [key: string]: ConditionKey | Context | string[] | number[];
}
```

Here's what my file `iam-policies.d.ts` looks like:

```
import { conditionResolvers }         from './conditions';
import { ConditionMap, ConditionKey } from 'iam-policies/dist/src/types';

declare module 'iam-policies/dist/src/types' {
    type Resolver = (data: any, expected: any) => boolean;

    type ConditionResolver = {
        [key in keyof typeof conditionResolvers]?: Resolver
    }

export interface Context {
    [key: string]: any;
}

}
```

I have errors such as "Duplicate Identifier 'ConditionBlock'", "Duplicate string index signature." and others that indicate `data` and `expected` in my conditionResolvers can't be of type `Date`. My tsconfig file is the same as the one found on the [NestJS Typescript Starter](https://github.com/nestjs/typescript-starter).

What I want is to be able to augment the type of the parameters in the Resolver object and the type of. The `ConditionResolver` is a collection of functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone in the future, I augmented them through the following method:

```
// External Imports
import { EffectBlock, ActionBlock, ResourceBlock, NotResourceBlock, Patterns } from 'iam-policies/dist/src/types';
// Project Imports
import { conditionResolvers }                                                                     from './iam/conditions';

declare module 'iam-policies' {
    interface ConditionMap {
        [key: string]: any;
    }

    type ConditionBlock = {
        [key in keyof typeof conditionResolvers]?: ConditionMap;
    }

    interface StatementInterface {
        sid?: string;
        effect?: EffectBlock;
        condition?: ConditionBlock;
    }

    type ConditionResolver = typeof conditionResolvers;

    interface NotActionBlock {
        notAction: Patterns;
    }

    type IdentityBasedType = StatementInterface & (ActionBlock | NotActionBlock) & (ResourceBlock | NotResourceBlock);
    export interface Context {
        [key: string]: any;
    }
    export interface EvaluateIdentityBasedInterface {
        action: string;
        resource: string;
        context?: Context;
    }

    class IdentityBasedPolicy {
        constructor(config: IdentityBasedType[], conditionResolver?: ConditionResolver);
        evaluate({ action, resource, context, }: EvaluateIdentityBasedInterface): boolean;
        can({ action, resource, context }: EvaluateIdentityBasedInterface): boolean;
        cannot({ action, resource, context, }: EvaluateIdentityBasedInterface): boolean;
    }

    type PrincipalMap = {
        [key in EEntityPolicyEnumPrincipal]?: EClient | EClient[] | string | string[];
    }
    interface PrincipalBlock {
        principal: PrincipalMap | Patterns;
    }
    interface NotPrincipalBlock {
        principal: PrincipalMap | Patterns;
    }

    type ResourceBasedType = StatementInterface & (PrincipalBlock | NotPrincipalBlock) & (ActionBlock | NotActionBlock) & (ResourceBlock | NotResourceBlock | {});

    export interface EvaluateResourceBasedInterface extends EvaluateIdentityBasedInterface {
        principal: string;
        principalType?: string;
    }

    class ResourceBasedPolicy {
        constructor(config: ResourceBasedType[], conditionResolver?: ConditionResolver);
        evaluate({ principal, action, resource, principalType, context, }: EvaluateResourceBasedInterface): boolean;
        can({ principal, action, resource, principalType, context, }: EvaluateResourceBasedInterface): boolean;
        cannot({ principal, action, resource, principalType, context, }: EvaluateResourceBasedInterface): boolean;
    }
}
```

It is not possible to change the types of a module, as a quick Google will confirm so. What I did was change the highter-level types, which were the classes, to achieve what I desired.